# multiprocessing Pool.map function issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a function like below, which takes a list and a path :

```
def my_function(items_list,directory):
     return(resulting number  of analyzing items_list for example [a,b] using specific file for example 'c:\\path')
```

to do parallel computation, im using multiprocessing module as follow:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def test_func(objs):
 pool= Pool(8) 
 result=pool.map(my_function,objs)
 return(result)


if __name__=='__main__':
    objects=[([a,b],'path1',),([c,d],'path2',),.....]
    result=test_funct(objects)
```

but it gives me the following error:
    TypeError: my_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'directory'

I changed the objects list format several times but it keeps giving me the same error.
does anybody know what the problem is?
(im using python33 on windows 7)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`multiprocessing.map` will not unpack the variables in your tuple. So `myfunction` is receiving one tuple argument, instead of a list and a string.

If you're using Python 3.3+ (which it appears you are), you can use [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap), which will expand the tuple:

```
 result = pool.starmap(my_function,objs)
```

If you're using Python 3.2 or lower, the easiest thing would be to make `my_function` take a single argument, and just expand the tuple in the body of the function:

```
def my_function(tup)
    items_list, directory = tup
```

If you can't change `my_function`, add a helper function that will do the unpacking for you:

```
def my_function_helper(tup):
    return my_function(*tup)
```

Comment: perfect as always. Thnaks Dano